# Get selected cell content

Tags: tornadofx

How can I get selected cell content for tableviews with enableCellEditing() ?
Using selectionModel I can get entire row, but not selected cell.

I try to implement copy cell to clipboard hotkey for my tableview. Probably I'm missing the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dig deeper in tornadofx I found solution for my own question

```
        shortcut("Ctrl+C") {
            if (!selectionModel.isEmpty) {
                Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().putString(selectedColumn?.getValue(selectedItem).toString())
            }
        }
```